# How to reset filter in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently I have multiple filters. I would like to reset the filter however, its not working.

```
showOnlyMyRequest(){
    this.requests = this.requests.filter(request => request.requestedBy === 'John Doe');
  }

showAllRequest(){
    this.requests = this.requests.filter(request => request.requestedBy === '*');
  }
```

In the above example the `showAllRequest()` doesn't reset the previous filter.

Comment: `.filter()` returns a new collection with the filtered elements only. If you want to be able to reset, keep the unfiltered collection somewhere else.

Comment: Actually I want to reset to default state. Remove all the previously applied filters.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

`The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.`

So your requests array becomes the one .filter() returned, you should stock your filtered values somewhere else if you need to either show your requests filtered or not.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you decide to send a parameter to your search function from your search text field you can try this.
let me know if there is a better solution so I can improve myself too. Thanks in advance.

```
   showAllRequest(parameter1){
  if (parameter1 === '') {
  /* call getmethod or the whole array variable got during get mehtod  
  */ 
  }
this.requests = this.requests.filter(request => request.requestedBy 
  === '*');
  }
```

coded version below :

```
 filterform(search) {
 if (search === '') {
        this.getFormSettings();
       }
   this.requests = this.requests.filter(request => 
 request.requestedBy.indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) >= 0 === '*');
}
```